# Angular download text as file, does not show new line characters in notepad

Tags: javascript, angular, utf-8, utf-16, utf

I'm downloading a text data as a `.txt` file, using javascript code in my Angular application.

Following is my code :

```
function download_text_as_file(data: string) {
    var element = document.createElement('a')
    element.style.display = 'none'
    element.setAttribute('href', "data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8,%EF%BB%BF" + encodeURIComponent(data))
    element.setAttribute('download', `file_name.txt`)
    document.body.appendChild(element)
    element.click()
    document.body.removeChild(element)
}
```

But when i open the downloaded file using Notepad in Windows, somehow it is not detecting the new line characters in the string.
However, the text is rendered properly when i open it using Notepad++.

I think that it might be the file encoding issue but the file is being saved in UTF-8 format and Notepad should have no problem decoding it.

Just FYI : I had opened the file using notepad and clicked on Save As, and it was giving the default option as UTF-8, which says the file is being saved correctly in UTF-8 format.

Should i use any other encoding format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the UTF format. Notepad has the restriction to see end lines as CRLF (\r\n), a restriction that Notepad++ doesn't have.

End lines are specific to the OS (some need CRLF, CR, or LF). What this means, is that you won't be able to modify the line breaks that you are getting from the server by changing the UTF format.

In order for you to see the line breaks in Notepad, you will have to replace the line breaks in your side with javascript (replace either \n or \r with \r\n).